# how can i break my do while with nested if/else if?

Tags: java, if-statement, break, do-while

this is the code that i have but i have to admit i have become a bit code blind and cant seem to see the problem eventhough i feel it is an easy one. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
   do{
        System.out.println("Command:");
        scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        String line;                        

        line = scan.nextLine();

        String[]SplitUpText;

        SplitUpText=line.split(" ");

        Command = SplitUpText[0];

        int param1=-1, param2=-1;

        if (Command.compareTo("move")==0)
        {
            if (SplitUpText.length>1)
            {
                param1=Integer.parseInt(SplitUpText[1]);
                if(SplitUpText.length>2)
                {
                    param2=Integer.parseInt(SplitUpText[2]);
                }
            }g.moveTo (param1, param2);


        }else if(Command.compareTo("circle")==0){

            if (SplitUpText.length>1)
            {
                param1=Integer.parseInt(SplitUpText[1]);
            }g.circle (param1);
        }else if(Command.compareTo("line")==0){
            if (SplitUpText.length>1)
            {
                param1=Integer.parseInt(SplitUpText[1]);
                if(SplitUpText.length>2)
                {
                    param2=Integer.parseInt(SplitUpText[2]);
                }
            }g.lineTo (param1, param2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Command");
        }

    } while (Command.compareTo ("end")!=0);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: its a program using a graphical user interface which is controlled by user input. i would just like to be able to end the program by the use of the while but i cant seem to make the do while do so.

Comment: I dont see the word `break` or `return` in any of your logic branches... when do you actually want to break? What have you tried that didn't work? In what way is this a problem?

Comment: that was the problem, i couldn't see where to put my break.   now have my break in and working

Comment: } else {
    if (Command.compareTo("end")==0){
     break;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Invalid Command");
   }

Comment: Include **attempted solutions and expected results**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally best practice to avoid it (by adding a condition to the `while` expression instead), but if you want to end the loop prematurely, you can use `break;`

Here's a simpler example:

```
int i;

i = 0;
do {
    ++i;
    System.out.println("Before: " + i);
    if (someSpecialCondition) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("After: " + i);
}
while (i < 5);
```

Let's suppose the special condition occurs when `i` has just become `3`, the output would be:

```
Before: 1
After: 1
Before: 2
After: 2
Before: 3
```

Note how the `break` terminated the loop. It can be used with all kinds of loops (`do..while`, `while`, and both kinds of `for`).

If you have nested loops and need to break the outer one from within the inner one, you should probably refactor that code into sub-methods. BUT, if you don't want to refactor, you can use a *directed* `break`:

```
int i, j;

outerLoop: for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        if (i == 2 && j == 2) {
            break outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

There, `outerLoop` labels the outer loop, and `break outerLoop` causes both the inner loop and the outer loop to terminate. Again, though, if you get into doing this, it's probably time to refactor.

More from the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15

Comment: ...and then read http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Patterns-Joshua-Kerievsky/dp/0321213351 or something like it

Comment: @DonBranson: Indeed. :-)

Comment: thank you, managed to get it to break within the final else. just trying to get it to close the graphics screen. thank you all!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ooops sorry, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using break statement.